# How to Aggregate an IFindFluent list in MongoDB C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I haven't found any relevant information regarding this anywhere, this is what I did:

```
var collection = database.GetCollection<Job>("jobs");
var result = collection.Find(filter);
```

What I'd like to do with the result is the following:

```
var buckets = result.Aggregate().BucketAuto(t => t.Salary, 10);
```

But the problem is that result is of type IFindFluent, for which Aggregate() does not work. Surely there has to be a solution for this, as I believe this is quite common.
I thought about casting the IFindFluent result to IMongoCollection but that just feels dirty.

Comment: You can have a `$match` aggregation stage to substitute for the `collection.Find...)`. Also, use the `Aggregate` method on the collection object.

Comment: @prasad_ i'd like to make an aggregation for the values that I already filtered, not to the initial collection

Answer (score 0):

you can't combine `Find` and `Aggregate`, because it's different underlying machineries. What you need is to get the same logic as in `Find(filter)` via `Match` stage like `Aggregate().Match(..).BuchetAuto(..)`